# Polymorphism java 8

Tags: java

i know how it works here

Polymorphism does not include instance fields. Methods yes, fields no. Baap b is a reference of type Baap when accessing fields (b.h). When accessing methods, b morphs into a Beta type (b.getH()).

```
class Baap
{
  public int h = 4;
  public int getH()
  {
    System.out.println("Baap "+h);
    return h;
  }
}
public class Beta extends Baap
{
  public int h = 44;
  public int getH()
  {
    System.out.println("Beta "+h);
    return h;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Baap betaInBaap = new Beta();
    System.out.println(betaInBaap.h+" "+betaInBaap.getH());
    Beta castedBeta = (Beta) betaInBaap;
    System.out.println(castedBeta.h+" "+castedBeta.getH());
  }
}
```

[image]

What I don't understand is the order of output

As Here o/p must be 4(calling b.h) followed by Beta 44(calling method b.geth()) and the method returns 44 as well so the first line must be 4 Beta 44 44

Comment: No. your print statement in the getH() method is executed before you get the result of getH() in your main method, so before that can be printed.

Comment: oh i get it! but still what about return it prints 44 before 4?

Comment: again: no, as I explained in my previous comment, the print of "Beta " + h is done before the print that calls that method, because it can not print it, before it receives the returned value of that method. And it sure won't print it in the same line, since they are two seperate println statements

Comment: i get it..thx @stultuske

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int h = 44;
  public int getH()
  {
    System.out.println("Beta "+h);         // print line 1
    return h;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Baap b = new Beta();
    System.out.println(b.h+" "+b.getH());  // print line 2
    Beta bb = (Beta) b;
    System.out.println(bb.h+" "+bb.getH()); // print line 3
  }
```

In your first print statement in your main method, you want it to print `b.h+ " "+ b.getH()`. It can't print this, before it knows the value returned by `b.getH();`

So, it runs `b.getH()` which prints (seperately) `System.out.println("Beta "+h);` 
before returning a value to the main method. (print line 1)

That explains your first line.
After the value is returned, the main method can now print print line 2, because it now knows what `b.getH()` has as result:

```
System.out.println(b.h+" "+b.getH());
```

This explains your second line in the output.
The same order is executed when running print line 3.